# Listar tabela com números crescentes com paginação

Tags: php, sql

Olá, estou fazendo um ranking de doadores, mas tive um pequeno problema
estou querendo listar todos os usuários e quero organizar por números crescentes, ex: **1,2,3,4,5,6..**

porem quando eu vou para a próxima página os números mantem

p.s: não posso listar por ID **(ORDER BY id ASC)**, pos se trata de um ranking, a query abaixo é somente para explicar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz algo do tipo, porém sem sucesso

```
$total_pages = $api->query('SELECT * FROM doadores')->numRows();
$page = isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

$num_results_on_page = 5;

$calc_page = ($page - 1) * $num_results_on_page;
if ($stmt = $api->query('SELECT * FROM doadores LIMIT ?,?', $calc_page, $num_results_on_page)->fetchAll()) {

$num = 0;
foreach ($stmt as $row){ ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $num++; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

...

PREV
1
2
3
4
...
120
NEXT

Comment: Não basta fazer `($page - 1)*$num_results_on_page + $num++` ao invés de apenas `$num++`?

Comment: @Woss no geral, ficaria do mesmo jeito '-'

Comment: Por que afirma isso?

Comment: @Woss $num = 1;  $calc_page = ($page - 1) * $num_results_on_page + $num++; = retorna sempre 2

Comment: Isso não é `$calc_page`, mas sim o seu `echo` dentro da tabela

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado. poderia responder a pergunta para eu marcar sua resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você também pode trazer direto do banco de dados, utilizando a função **row_number()**:

```sql
select 
    -- o 'order by' abaixo deve ser o mesmo ... -> 
    row_number() over (order by ranking) sequencia
    , * 
from 
    doadores
    --> deste 'order by'
order by ranking 
limit 5
offset 0
```

Um exemplo: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e64b9/13/0)